# Center image within a div (while also considering positioning)

Tags: css, html, positioning, center

I'm current working on creating a Google home page clone for a project, and needed some help with centering the Google logo in my div. I've looked everywhere and I've been able to somewhat center my logo, but I have a feeling that it's not fully centered because of the positioning of my header in the top right. What should I do?

Here's the dropbox link to my html and css:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/28kvu16921vm5dh/j4cgg7cA2A

Comment: looks like we need to get closed to your computer, touch on the keyboard to see what's wrong in your webpage at the address posted in your question.

Comment: Some code would be helpful.

Comment: Here's the dropbox link to my html and css code: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/28kvu16921vm5dh/j4cgg7cA2A

Comment: Give `#middle` `text-align: center;`.

Comment: The text-align doesn't seem to work. It seems to me that it's already centered, something's just up with the positioning on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change

```
#header ul {
float: right; }
```

with

```
#header ul {
right: 0;
position: absolute; }
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without `div` in HTML code

```
<img style= "margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto">
```

Comment: Is the link to that site necessary for this answer?